# Sufficient and necessary conditions for order relations describing a certain system of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, order-theory

I call a *system of precedences* $U$ a set of nonempty subsets of some poset. I will denote $A<B \Leftrightarrow \forall a\in A, b\in B: a<b$ for sets $A,B\in U$.

Find sufficient and necessary restrictions on binary relations $<$ and $\subseteq$ such that there exists a system $U$ of precedences such that they are exactly (up to isomorphism) $<$ and $\subseteq$ on $U$.

*(I wrote my conditions for these operations for a system of precedences in https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/85951/39512 but I'm not sure if these conditions are right.)*

The proposed conditions in that answer can be written as the following:

- $\subseteq$ is a non-strict partial order relation and $<$ is a strict partial order relation.
- $\forall a,b,a_1,b_1\in U:(a<b \wedge a_1\subseteq a \wedge b_1\subseteq b \Rightarrow a_1<b_1)$.

(Not relevant to the question, just where the questions appeared from) Systems of precedences origin from subsets of $U$ being sets of operations, where operations with higher precedences should be applies before operations of lower precedences.)

You may assume that all sets in consideration are finite.

Comment: Is your partial ordering [strict or non-strict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders)?

Comment: @AlexVong You see I use $<$ symbol denoting strict partial order

Comment: I couldn't understand the phrase "such that they are exactly $<$ and $\subseteq$ on $U$" - maybe an example would help. What set are the binary relations $<$ and $\subseteq$ defined on? Where do you use the definition of $<$ for sets ($A<B\iff \cdots$)?

Comment: I don't understand the question about $\subseteq$: it is the inclusion relation over sets, so in my opinion it doesn't make sense to redefine it (by adding restrictions).

Comment: @Dap I mean that we need to check if *arbitrary* binary relations $<$ and $\subseteq$ conforming to the above conditions (being partial orders, etc.) are the relations (with the same names $<$ and $\subseteq$) for a system $U$ of precedences, where $\subseteq$ is set-inclusion and $<$ is defined in the first paragraph of my question

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I ask if an arbitrary partial order $\subseteq$ conforming to the above conditions can be a set-inclusion relation for a system of precedences.

Comment: Counterexample to my answer proposed in the question (so we need to find another answer): Consider $U = \{\{0, 1\}, \{2, 3\}, \{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{ 3 \} \}$
with the usual order of the digits and induced order of singletons, but with
$\{0, 1\}$ incomparable with $\{2, 3\}$. It also cannot be a system of precedences via any isomorhism $\varphi$,
because $\varphi \{0, 1\} < \varphi \{2, 3\}$ is implied by $\forall x \in
\varphi \{ 0 \}, y \in \varphi \{ 2 \} : x < y$ (etc.) what is implied by
$\varphi \{ 0 \} < \varphi \{ 2 \}$ what is implied by $\{ 0 \} < \{ 2 \}$.

Comment: Is your supposed counterexample not isomorphic to $V=\{\{0,1,4\},\{2,3\},\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$? Am I missing something?

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen As I understood, $\subseteq$ is only a binary relation, so in the proposed counterexample the isomorphism $\varphi$ not necessarily preserves "unions", becuse they are undefined. That is $\varphi\{0,1\}$ not necessarily equals $\varphi\{0\}\cup \varphi\{1\}$. For instance, if we take $V$ from your comment then, I guess, $\varphi\{0\}=\{0\}$, $\varphi\{1\}=\{1\}$, but $\varphi\{0,1\}=\{0,1,4\}$.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen For elemements $\{ 0, 1 \}$ and $\{ 2, 3 \}$ of $U$ we have (see my above
comment) $\varphi \{ 0, 1 \} < \varphi \{ 2, 3 \}$. So if your isomorphism was
hold, we would have $\{ 0, 1, 4 \} < \{ 2, 3 \}$ (in the order induced by the
order of singletons), what is false. So my counterexample is not isomorphic to
your $V$.

Comment: I added the extra element 4 precisely to satisfy the condition "but with $\{0,1\}$ incomparable with $\{2,3\}$" (quoting you).

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen I understand why you added $4$. Oh well, I see an error in my counterexample: $\varphi \{0, 1\} < \varphi \{2, 3\}$ may be not implied by $\forall x \in \varphi \{ 0 \}, y \in \varphi \{ 2 \} : x < y$ (etc.) So you may be right, I will check it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(A,\subseteq^A,<^A)$ satisfy your proposed conditions. For $a\in A$, let $f(a)=\{b\in A\mid b\subseteq^A a\}$. Let $U$ be the range of $f$. Now, consider $a,b\in A$. Assume first $b\subseteq^A a$. Then for every $c\in f(b)$, it holds that $c\subseteq^A b\subseteq^A a$ and hence, by the transitivity of $\subseteq^A$, we have $c\subseteq^A a$ and therefore $c\in f(c)$. So, $f(b)\subseteq f(a)$. Assume then $b\not\subseteq^A a$. Then $b\in f(b)$ but $b\notin f(a)$, so $f(b)\not\subseteq f(a)$. We have shown that $b\subseteq^A a$ iff $f(b)\subseteq f(a)$. This also implies that $f$ is one-to-one.

Assume now that $b <^A a$. Let $a'\in f(a)$ and $b'\in f(b)$. Then $a' \subseteq^A a$ and $b' \subseteq^A b$, so it follows from your assumptions that $b' <^A a'$. Thus $f(b) < f(a)$. On the other hand, $a\in f(a)$ and $b\in f(b)$, and therefore $f(b) < f(a)$ implies, in particular, that $b <^A a$.